# Voronoi Tessellation] Find out which point I'm referencing

Tags: d3.js, voronoi

I've got a project using this [Voronoi Tessellation](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366) plugin with series of coordinates representing locations of temperature sensors - I'm thinking of using JSON to represent their locations and detected temperature values.

What I need to is to display the temperature value of the sensor(point) I'm referencing to(the area where I'm mouse-hovering) when mouse-hovering an area.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Voronoi-Geom

I've been reading this documentation again and again but still can't figure out whether detecting which specific point that the mouse-hovering area belongs to is possible.

Has anyone tried this before?  Are there good examples about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, you want to display text at the vertices point when a user mouses into the voronoi partition?

You could do this by handling the mouseenter/leave events of each path:

```
path.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", function(d, i) {
  return "q" + (i % 9) + "-9";
})
.attr("d", polygon)
.on("mouseenter", function(d,i){
  if (!someTexts[i]) { // get some fake value
    someTexts[i] = (Math.random()*100).toFixed(1);
  }
  // append text
  currentText = svg.append("text")
    .text(someTexts[i])
    .attr("transform","translate(" + vertices[i] + ")")
    .attr("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle");
})
.on("mouseleave", function(d,i){
  // remove text
  currentText.remove();
});
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ikD5NWA4kAG6ClorYXU?p=preview).